# mod_rewrite rule that will stop triggering a 404

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have page

```
www.mydomain.com/cms/index.php
```

I need a mod_rewrite rule that will stop triggering showing a 404 page when I enter something like

```
www.mydomain.com/cms/keyword1/keyword2/keyword3
```

or

```
www.mydomain.com/cms/keyword1/keyword2/999-keyword3.html
```

and so on. What I want is to pass the every thing after the [cms] to the index file for processing

so

```
[www.mydomain.com/cms/keyword1/keyword2/keyword3]
```

will return

```
[keyword1/keyword2/keyword3]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in you .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ cms.php?content=$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

This will redirect the user to your customize page of cms.php, or you can change the name, and will send the page requested in $_GET['content'];

the content of the cms.php can be

```
       echo $_GET['content'];
       // should output "cms/keyword1/keyword2/999-keyword3.html" in your case
```